# example of texture mapping in pyglet

Tags: textures, pyglet

Using pyglet, I am trying to create a UVSphere mesh, and on its surface I would like to display a mercator-projection map. In researching examples of pyglet texture mapping, I have found:

- Nehe [tutorial 6 in pyglet](https://code.google.com/p/pyglet-hene/source/browse/trunk/nehe_in_pyglet/lesson06.py). However this uses immediate mode, and shows the entire texture on each cube face.
- [pyglet_obj_test](https://github.com/greenmoss/pyglet_obj_test), which **looks** like it includes texture maps. However instead of showing the chosen texture, it shows an even color.
- [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778913/mapping-a-texture-to-a-quad-opengl-and-pyglet), which looks like there was an answer with a solution. However the referenced gists showing working code have disappeared.
- Another [implementation](https://bitbucket.org/djfroofy/miru/src/fe13609c4f3e/miru?at=default), referenced [in the pyglet google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pyglet-users/cnCS_tkS6pA)

Are there any simple examples of a working mesh + texture map in pyglet?

**Edit:** I found out the [pyglet_obj_test](https://github.com/greenmoss/pyglet_obj_test) code is looking for lines in the `.obj` file starting with `vt` in order to create texture mapping coordinates. However the Wavefront exporter in Blender apparently has no option to export this information. I exported the same mesh with each of the other available types:

- `COLLADA (.dae)`
- `Stanford (.ply)`
- `Stl (.stl)`
- `3D Studio (.3ds)`
- `Autodesk FBX (.fbx)`
- `X3D Extensible 3D (.x3d)`

Perhaps there's a pyglet importer for one of these formats...

**Edit 2:** I clearly have a poor understanding of the wavefront format. It seems `vt` lines are *not* necessary. What I was missing is full `f` maps.

For instance, to simplify things way down, I created a 3d mesh that was actually a single square, with a texture mapped onto it. In Blender it shows the square with distorted texture, but the built-in wavefront exporter produces a single line of texture mapping `f 2//1 1//1 3//1 4//1`. These should apparently instead be something like `f 2/0/1 1/0/1 3/0/1 4/0/1` (note there should be a number between the two slashes).

Apparently Blender only does a full (proper?) export of these lines if a texture is *UV mapped*. Applying a texture without a UV Map renders properly in Blender, but I guess the wavefront exporter doesn't properly handle it. Perhaps it's time for me to submit a Blender bug report...

Answer (score 1):

I pursued the [pyglet_obj_test](https://github.com/greenmoss/pyglet_obj_test) solution further and got it working. So, to answer my own question, here's a complete example:

- Using Blender, create a mesh with a UV-mapped texture. The UV-mapping is important! If it is working properly, you will see the texture applied within Blender's 3d view.
- Export the mesh from Blender using the Wavefront format, including normals.
- Clone pyglet_obj_test, and run `display.py your_mesh.obj`